# What are we Doing with Markdown Bugs / Inconsistencies

Tags: support, markdown, meta

What are we doing with Markdown bugs / inconsistencies?
Should they be

- Each posted as a new question
- All added to [Preview should match the posted view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view/23291) or a different question
- Forgotten about 'cause we all know they're there & the dev team have better things to work on

Edit: I just added one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view/23291#23291) - I *think* it's new

Comment: I don't get that "edit", you're linking to the same place from the "preview".

Answer (score 3):

Go here for server side:

http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/

Go here for client side:

http://github.com/derobins/wmd
http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/

Answer (score 2):

Embrace Open Source and [fix it](http://github.com/derobins/wmd)!

Comment: Isn't SO using its own super-secret-special version/

Comment: Also it previews OK so looks like it's in the SO code.

Comment: It's the SO branch. Provide a patch for it and they can consider if they want to add it.

Comment: How do you provide the patch without the SO source?

Comment: @Nathan: I'm puzzled. You can download the source. It is *Open* Source.

Comment: @John if, hypothetically, we have created a patch, how do we submit it and have them consider it? More importantly, where on that site?

Comment: @Maxim Z.: http://wiki.github.com/rakudo/rakudo/steps-to-create-a-patch - There are a lot of tutorials about git and github. Read them!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would take the time to find and fix the bug in the available repository.

However, if you don't, search and make sure it isn't already found here on meta.  If it is, submit a "I can confirm this bug with the following screenshots/info/tests/etc" answer.

If it doesn't yet exist, file a separate bug report (question) on meta.  Posting it to aggregate bug lists is useful for tracking, but the system is set up to have a "bug" tag and a status completed, deferred, or declined tag.  An aggregate bug/question can't easily be marked completed/deferred/defined since only one or two of the bugs may have been addressed.